# subset array by sequence where subscript out of bounds

Tags: arrays, r, subset

I need to create a new array that includes any `dimnames(tmp)` that are between 1000 and 2000.  I know that `dimnames(tmp)[1]` has missing values from 1000 to 2000 so thats why I am getting that error.  However I still need to extract all `dimnames(tmp)[1]` that are between 1000 and 2000 to a new array called `tmp2`.  I have been trying

```
tmp2= tmp[c(seq(from=1000, to=2000))),,]
```

`tmp` looks like

```
attributes(tmp)
$dim
[1]   172 11688    13

$dimnames
$dimnames[[1]]
  [1] "1257" "1206" "1175" "1223" "1303" "1379" "1345" "1322" "1376" "1443" "1435"
 [12] "1483" "1496" "1474" "1435" "1377" "1244" "1149" "1273" "1362" "1429" "1527"
 [23] "1470" "1462" "1361" "1380" "1490" "1490" "1577" "1466" "1511" "1545" "1536"
 [34] "1592" "1620" "1698" "1722" "1712" "1689" "1805" "1780" "1829" "1952" "2106"
 [45] "2203" "2187" "2199" "2136" "2098" "2052" "2053" "1952" "1977" "1965" "1894"
 [56] "1843" "1803" "1782" "1770" "1770" "1770" "1748" "1728" "1722" "1615" "1483"
 [67] "1458" "1431" "1425" "1410" "1425" "1410" "1410" "1403" "1402" "1383" "1415"
 [78] "1489" "1393" "1384" "1379" "1364" "1346" "1327" "1357" "1357" "1454" "1480"
 [89] "1316" "1273" "1239" "1383" "1531" "1531" "1587" "1634" "1736" "1640" "1682"
[100] "1797" "1996" "2067" "2001" "1970" "2169" "2198" "2361" "2328" "2253" "2239"
[111] "2173" "2333" "2275" "2269" "2276" "2411" "2566" "2673" "2673" "2702" "2597"
[122] "2568" "2638" "2786" "2805" "2839" "2788" "2700" "2669" "2599" "2568" "2546"
[133] "2536" "2521" "2498" "2476" "2503" "2428" "2404" "2418" "2431" "2471" "2476"
[144] "2505" "2484" "2547" "2668" "2731" "2716" "2553" "2437" "2437" "2367" "2355"
[155] "2382" "2439" "2455" "2399" "2338" "2267" "2192" "2169" "2223" "2255" "2277"
[166] "2250" "2192" "2206" "2199" "2212" "2166" "2161"

$dimnames[[2]]
NULL

$dimnames[[3]]
 [1] "day"      "month"    "year"     "snowpack" "pet"      "precip"   "snowfall"
 [8] "wy"       "yd"       "wyd"      "snowmelt" "rainfall" "recharge"
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `%in%`:

```
tmp2 <- tmp[dimnames(tmp)[[1]] %in%  seq(from=1000, to=2000)), , ]
```